# Inserting a templated letterhead into existing word document via a macro along with an image at a specific line

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, ms-office

I have a very specific question. I have to insert letterheads and a signature in many word documents as a daily task. I'm looking to automate this procedure through a macro or other solution so I can focus on other tasks. What are the best ways to go about this?

Comment: Very cumbersome. Consider the opposite. Take the template and transfer your document into it, formatting and modifying it in the process.

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/20788-replace-apply-new-header-multiple-files.html

Comment: Best process, using MS Word, is to have a template for your letterhead and type or copy the text into a document created from that template. Why are you trying to add the letterhead after the text? http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/LetterheadRibbon.htm http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm This is more of a Word question than it is a programming question.